# How to prevent negative/minus input values in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Actually i have a input control with plus & minus buttons, its working fine in angular 6 but now i want to prevent negative values when i decrements. How can i prevent it?

HTML:-

```
<span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer" (click)="travelersMinus($event)">-</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="{{changeCount}}" />
```

TS:-

```
travelersMinus(evnet: Event){
        this.changeCount -= 1;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can handle it in `ts` file itself with simple check.

```
travelersMinus(evnet: Event){
        if(this.changeCount - 1 >= 0 ){
           this.changeCount -= 1;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an input of type number with a `min="0"`:

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Comment: Because this doesn't prevent user typing in a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

try below code, you can modify if you want to change event and also want to move logic in to ts file and from there you can call the method :

```
<input min='0' type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the validation more often it is recommended that you create a custom validator. You can do this using following docs:

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators